# ¿Cómo controlar la duración de un toast?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

A grandes rasgos, el toast dice si la respuesta es bien o mal en base a la resolución de un problema aritmético. Al ser de aritmética nos encontramos que son cálculos rápidos.
Uso `"Toast.LENGTH_SHORT"` para dar la duración mas pequeña del mismo, pero aun así siento que es demasiada (2.2 Segundos aproximadamente), hay alguna forma de que dure menos? Medio segundo?

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
    fun AppCompatActivity.toast(status: ToastStatus, message: String, length: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) {
    val inflater = layoutInflater
    val viewGroup: ViewGroup? = null
    val layout: ViewGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.costom_toast, viewGroup, false) as ViewGroup
    val text: TextView = layout.findViewById(R.id.textNuevo)
    val image: ImageView = layout.findViewById(R.id.imagenNuevo)
    val icon = when (status) {
        ToastStatus.SUCCESS -> R.drawable.icdone
        ToastStatus.ERROR -> R.drawable.icfail
        ToastStatus.FAIL -> R.drawable.icfaildos
     }
    image.setBackgroundResource(icon)
    text.text = message
    with (Toast(applicationContext)) {
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0)
        duration = length
        view = layout
        show()
    }
}
```

Un enum para ver los "estados":

```
 enum class ToastStatus {
    SUCCESS,
    ERROR,
    FAIL
}
```

Y los mando llamar:

```
    toast(ToastStatus.FAIL, "Perdiste!\nPuntaje menor a 0")
toast(ToastStatus.SUCCESS, "Correcto +100")
toast(ToastStatus.ERROR, "Incorrecto -100\nResultado: $resPar")
```

Como puedo hacer que la duracion sea menor a la que esta "predefinida"
NOTA: el toast es uno personalizado, recurriendo a un layo externo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clase `Toast` no soporta duraciones personalizadas. Si quieres una duración más corta que `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` debes cerrar el toast manualmente con el método `cancel()`

```
with(Toast(applicationContext)) {
    setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0)
    duration = length
    view = layout
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        show()
        delay(500) // medio segundo
        cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: He añadido "lifecycleScope.launch{}" pero me da un error

Comment: agrega este import `import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope`. Si te sigue dando error es porque tienes una versión desactualizada de la librería Lifecycle. Entonces agrega esta dependencia en tu archivo gradle `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1"`

Comment: Va bro, gracias; funciono a la perfeccion. 
Oye, disculpa el atrevimiento, pero.... ¿Como aprendiste todo esto?, ¿cual fue tu curva de aprendizaje?

Comment: Si preguntas como aprender android, te recomiendo hacer el [curso oficial](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course), luego lee la documentación oficial y si te quedan dudas busca respuestas en este sitio. Para mantenterte actualizado puedes leer las noticias que publican [acá](https://developer.android.com/news), seguir su [blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers) en medium o suscribirte a su [canal de youtube](https://www.youtube.com/c/AndroidDevelopers/videos)